# Have we ever seen a Pokémon poop or pee in any of the canon?

Tags: pokemon

According to [this highly-upvoted Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LowStakesConspiracies/comments/df4bez/pok%C3%A9mon_dont_poo_or_pee_because_their_waste/),

> Pokémon don’t poo or pee because their waste byproduct is expelled through use of their special moves.

How much truth is there in it? Have we ever seen a Pokémon poop or pee in any of the official work?

Comment: "According to this highly-upvoted Reddit post" *in the **r/LowStakesConspiracies** subreddit*

Comment: Well there's always Squirtle...

Answer (score 28):

This is addressed in at least one Pokédex entry; for Darumaka, in White, X and Omega Ruby:

> Darumaka's droppings are hot, so people used to put them in their clothes to keep themselves warm.

There are a few Pokémon that don't have droppings, but I think they are the exception rather than the rule.

Guzzlord:

> A dangerous Ultra Beast, it appears to be eating constantly, but for some reason its droppings have never been found.

Galarian Weezing:

> This Pokémon consumes particles that contaminate the air. Instead of leaving droppings, it expels clean air.

The way that both the Guzzlord and Weezing entries are written, I'd feel confident to say that they are the exception rather than the rule, and most Pokémon do leave droppings - the fact that Guzzlord and Weezing don't is exceptional enough that it needed special mention in the Pokédex.

Comment: This answers the question "Do Pokémon pee and poop?", which is good to know, but doesn't actually answer the OP's question about if we ever have seen them do it

Comment: I only comment this because you already have a very complete answer on the textural evidence - in the original Sinnoh games, the lady who makes mulch comments that it is produced "by mixing high-grade soil with Pokémon...um...you know..." which seems to be a further comment on (most) Pokémon defecating.

Comment: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Turtonator_(Pok%C3%A9mon) - If you go hunting around the comics, you'll be able to find some pictures of Turtonator's explosive droppings

Comment: @Valorum I think that’s worth an answer on its own.